# PDO Error with function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello i am using PDO 1st time and getting error ... dont no where am i wrong here is my code

```
function student_one_image($student_id){
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $STH = $DBH->query("SELECT * from school_students, school_student_one_image where (school_student_one_image.student_id = school_students.student_id) 
    and school_student_one_image.student_id = '$student_id'");
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $row = $STH->fetch();
    return $row
```

error is Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

and if i am trying using mysql it work

```
function student_one_image($student_id){
    $data= mysql_query("SELECT * from school_students, school_student_one_image where (school_student_one_image.student_id = school_students.student_id) 
    and school_student_one_image.student_id = '$student_id'");
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($data);
    return $result;
```

please help

Comment: Did you output the values of your `$host`, `$dbname`, `$user` and  `$pass` variables inside the function? It could be that they are empty

Comment: yes i have tried both ways .... putting direct also (username and pass) but still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variables `$host`, `$dbname`, `$user` and `$pass` are out of scope [1] since you're using them within a function.
You can either pass them like this:

```
function student_one_image($student_id, $host, $dbname, $user, $pass) {
```

Or change their scope by adding the following line to the top of your function:

```
global $host, $dbname, $user, $pass;
```

[1] http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php